# How in C# best object-oriented style to call appropriate calculation class method?

Tags: c#

I have a class AnnuityContext that contains the data for annuity payments on the loan.
Сlass contains methods for calculating annuity payments in two ways - equal and differentiated payments - CalculationDifferential and CalculationEqual.

```
public class AnnuityContext : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //...

    internal void CalculationDifferential()
    {
      //...
    }

    internal void CalculationEqual()
    {
      //...
    }

}
```

MainPage have combobox and button. When button pressed, depending on the combobox selection,   the appropriate method will be called :

```
private void buttonCalculation_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (flag == 1)
      this.AnnuityData.CalculationDifferential();
    else
      this.AnnuityData.CalculationEqual();
}
```

My question is how in a more object-oriented style to perform the same task. May be create method Calculation and call from that function CalculationDifferential() and CalculationEqual() ?

```
internal void Calculation()
{
   //...
}
```

Comment: It really depends on the implementation of CalcuationDifferential and CalculationEqual.

Comment: From MSDN docs `Internal types or members are accessible only within files in the same assembly`. Perhaps you are assuming that it is somehow equivalent to **inner** classes.

Answer (score 3):

I would use inheritance and polymorphism:

```
void Main()
{
    Process(new DifferentialAnnuityContext());
    Process(new EqualAnnuityContext());
}

public static void Process(AnnuityContext context)
{
    context.Calculate();
}

public abstract class AnnuityContext
{
    public abstract void Calculate();
}

public class DifferentialAnnuityContext : AnnuityContext
{
    public override void Calculate()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Differential");
    }
}

public class EqualAnnuityContext : AnnuityContext
{
    public override void Calculate()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Equal");
    }
}
```

You can see that the `Process` method does not know, nor care, which of the two (or more) types it gets called with.

This would remove the need for the code that needs to invoke the calculation to know which one to call, there is only one.

You can test the above program in [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net)

Answer (score 0):

If you really think you are going to create "lots" of different formulas for the calculation, you might consider a "calculation object" and letting the UI select the one to use.

You can create such an object in (at least) 2 ways:

1. Define a base class for the calculation.  This is effectively the "Template" pattern.  Something like:

public class LoanCalculatorBase
{

protected double PerformCalculationDerived(InputData data)
   {
     // Override this in derived classes
   }

public double PerformCalculation(InputData data)
   {
       PerformCalculationDerived(data);
   }

}

**NOTE:**  You could also make PerformCalculation the class to be overridden.  If you have than one function needed for the calculation (manageable pieces), you should consider an override for each "part" of the calculation.  If it is trivial, just override the single function.  The effectively defines the interface for the function via the base class.  At run time, you create an instance of your **derived** class, but use a base class pointer.

**NOTE:** You can also make the class abstract (no implementation) or make the PerformCalculationBase(...) abstract (so the deriver is forced to implement *something*).

1. Use an interface.  This defines how other class can access your calculator, but not anything about what is actually inside it (mostly).  Then you just need to create a calculator that satisfies the interface.  Instead of using a base class pointer, you use an interface pointer for accessing it.

public Interface ICalculator
{
   protected double PerformCalculationDerived(InputData data);
}

Keep an ICaculator reference in your class.  Initialize to an instance of whatever calculation you want to use by default (must inherit/implement ICalculator) and change it as needed when the user picks a new one.  Then call it like this:

// In class
private ICalculator calc = null;

// In function:
result = calc(data);

Which way you choose may or may not have deep discussions associated with it.  I prefer interfaces because they are more focused on the exact thing you want something to provide (contractual).

C# will let you define multiple interfaces but only one base class for a derived class.

Was this helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use an abstract class to create an object responsible for the selection of an annuity formula

```
#region CalculationFormula implementation
public abstract class CalculationFormulaBase
{
    public abstract List<AnnuityPayment> Execute(AnnuityContext context);
}

public class CalculationFormulaDifferential : CalculationFormulaBase
{
    public override List<AnnuityPayment> Execute(AnnuityContext context)
    {
        decimal refundPrincipal = (decimal)context.PrincipalAmount / context.LoanTerm;
        double monthlyRate = (double)context.InterestRate / 12 / 100;

        decimal loanBalance = context.PrincipalAmount;

        List<AnnuityPayment> annuityPayments = new List<AnnuityPayment>(context.LoanTerm + 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < context.LoanTerm; i++)
        {
            decimal refundInterest = loanBalance * Convert.ToDecimal(monthlyRate);

            loanBalance = loanBalance - refundPrincipal;

            annuityPayments.Add(new AnnuityPayment { Period = String.Format("{0:#}", i + 1), RefundPrincipal = refundPrincipal, RefundInterest = refundInterest, MonthlyPayment = refundPrincipal + refundInterest, LoanBalance = loanBalance });
        }

        return annuityPayments;
    }
}

public class CalculationFormulaEqual : CalculationFormulaBase
{
    public override List<AnnuityPayment> Execute(AnnuityContext context)
    {
        double monthlyRate = (double)context.InterestRate / 12 / 100;

        double coefficient = monthlyRate / (1 - Math.Pow(1 + monthlyRate, -context.LoanTerm));
        decimal refundAnnuity = (decimal)context.PrincipalAmount * Convert.ToDecimal(coefficient);

        decimal loanBalance = context.PrincipalAmount;

        List<AnnuityPayment> annuityPayments = new List<AnnuityPayment>(context.LoanTerm + 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < context.LoanTerm; i++)
        {
            decimal refundInterest = loanBalance * Convert.ToDecimal(monthlyRate);

            decimal refundPrincipal = refundAnnuity - refundInterest;

            loanBalance = loanBalance - refundPrincipal;

            annuityPayments.Add(new AnnuityPayment { Period = String.Format("{0:#}", i + 1), RefundPrincipal = refundPrincipal, RefundInterest = refundInterest, MonthlyPayment = refundPrincipal + refundInterest, LoanBalance = loanBalance });
        }

        return annuityPayments;
    }
}
#endregion
```

In the class AnnuityContext I have created properties to get or set the formula for calculating the annuity payments

```
public class AnnuityContext : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        private IList<AnnuityPayment> m_AnnuityPayments = new List<AnnuityPayment>();
        public IEnumerable<AnnuityPayment> AnnuityPayments
        {
            get
            {
                return m_AnnuityPayments;
            }
        }

        private CalculationFormulaBase m_CalculationFormula;
        public CalculationFormulaBase CalculationFormula
        {
            get { return m_CalculationFormula; }
            set
            {
                if (m_CalculationFormula != value)
                {
                    m_CalculationFormula = value;

                    EmptyAnnuityPayments();
                }
            }
        }

      //...
   }
```

In the same class, I created a function Calculation () which calls the correct formula for calculating and updating some controls on the page

```
internal void Calculation()
{
    m_AnnuityPayments = CalculationFormula.Execute(this);

    NotifyPropertyChanged("AnnuityPayments");

    //...
}
```

When the page is initialized in Silverlight I set the defait formula for calculating annuity:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.AnnuityData = new AnnuityContext { VehiclePrice = 500000, DownPaymentPercent = 20, LoanTerm = 36, InterestRate = 15, Summ = 600000, PeriodsCount = 60, RateString = "16" };
    sliderPrincipalAmount.Value = 400000;

    //this.AnnuityData.CalculationFormula = new CalculationFormulaDifferential();
    this.AnnuityData.CalculationFormula = new CalculationFormulaEqual();


    this.DataContext = this.AnnuityData;

    buttonCalculation.Focus();
}
```